# Why the log "End-Test" is not printed in run but does while debugging?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, concurrentdictionary

When I run this test, The log "End-Test" is not printed, but when I debug it step by step, it does printed.
What is the reson for this ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NUnit.Framework;

  namespace Tests.Integrations
  {
   [TestFixture]
   public class Test
   {
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<DateTimeOffset, string> _log;

    static Test()
    {
        _log = new ConcurrentDictionary<DateTimeOffset, string>();
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("Why_End-Test_is_notPrinted")]
    public async Task main(string testId)
    {
        LogWrite($"START-Test");
        var sucssess = await SomethingSlow();
        LogWrite($"END-Test, sucssess:{sucssess}");
        LogSave(testId);
    }
    private async Task<bool> SomethingSlow()
    {
        return await Task<bool>.Run(() =>
        {
            LogWrite("Something Slow In");
            for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) { };
            LogWrite("Something Slow Out");
            return true;
        });
    }
    public void LogWrite(string msg)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var time = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            var ts = time
                .ToLocalTime()
                .ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss,fffffff");
            var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            _log.TryAdd(time, $"{ts}-[{threadId}]: {msg}");
        });
    }
    public void LogSave(string testId)
    {
        var sorted = LogSort();
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sorted, Formatting.Indented);
        string Path = $"{DirectoryPath.GetDirectoryPath()}";
        using (
           System.IO.StreamWriter file =
           new System.IO.StreamWriter($"{Path}\\ActualResults\\{testId}.json"))
        {
            file.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }
    public List<string> LogSort()
    {
        var sortedLog = new List<string>();
        var logKeys = _log.Keys.ToList();
        logKeys.Sort();
        logKeys.ForEach(key =>
        {
            string value = string.Empty;
            if (_log.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                sortedLog.Add(value);
        });
        return sortedLog;
    }
 }
```

}

The log output without debugging:

```
[
  "16/08/20 11:27:34,1133986-[9]: START-Test",
  "16/08/20 11:27:34,1144001-[11]: Something Slow In",
  "16/08/20 11:27:39,3383941-[9]: Something Slow Out"
]
```

The log output with debugging step by step:

```
[
  "16/08/20 11:29:18,8003608-[9]: START-Test",
  "16/08/20 11:29:18,8033588-[10]: Something Slow In",
  "16/08/20 11:29:24,1967210-[10]: Something Slow Out",
  "16/08/20 11:29:35,0146056-[9]: END-Test, sucssess:True"
]
```

The expected result is as it is printed in the log while debugging step by step.
Because I expect that when awaiting in the main task to the task "SomethingSlow()", the remaining lines of code in main task shell not be treated untill "SomethingSlow()" returns, and then the log("End-Test") should be handled.
In addition the moving between the threads is not as excpected because both lines "Something Slow In" and "Something Slow Out" are in the same task, so they have to be in the same thread, but in running without debugging it is not like that.

Comment: Why the `public async Task main` method starts with a lowercase m?

Comment: Also why the `LogWrite` initiates a fire-and-forget task? Is this a bug or a conscious decision?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `public async Task main` is valid because it's being run from a test framework

Comment: When you debug, you give enough time for the `LogWrite($"END-Test, sucssess:{sucssess}");` task to finish, that's why.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the code without debugging, the task doesn't finish in time. So you must await it.

Cnange `LogWrite` method:

```
public Task LogWrite(string msg)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ...
    });
}
```

Then await this method:

```
public async Task main(string testId)
{
    await LogWrite($"START-Test");
    var sucssess = await SomethingSlow();
    await LogWrite($"END-Test, sucssess:{sucssess}");
    LogSave(testId);
}
```

Also simplify `SomethingSlow` method:

```
private Task<bool> SomethingSlow()
{
    return Task<bool>.Run(() =>
    {
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and the first and third blocks while useful, are irrelevant.

Comment: By the way, Something slow should be change also to async await as follows 
'''
private Task<bool> SomethingSlow()
        {
            return Task<bool>.Run( async() =>
            {
                await LogWrite("Something Slow In");
                for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) { };
                await LogWrite("Something Slow Out");
                return true;
            });
        }
'''